# UILabel with frame

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am adding a `UILabel` dynamically, and I don't know how to select the frame so that frame exactly fits the text and font size.

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myView.frame];
```

The `initWithFrame` above is obviously too big for the label.
Is there a way to make it so that the frame is fits exactly with the width and height of the label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `-sizeToFit` method to fit the size of font:

```
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: I tried only this solution and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sizeWithFont:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3a) or [`sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3aforWidth%3alineBreakMode%3a) to determine the size of your string with a certain font. Then you can set the UILabels frame to have that size.